# Displaying angular components in row/column fashion

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an array with Angular2 components in the below fashion.

```
[[ "TextArea",  "0", "1" ],
[["PieChart", "1", "0"],
[["Grid", "2", "0"]]
```

Here the first parameter is the component name and the next two are column location and row location. I want to display all these components on my page based on their column and location. First I want to display all the items in column 0.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the last sentence of your post. So you want to display everything in column 0 so all the column values will be 0 and this will end up in PieChart and Grid being in the same column ?

Comment: No. Components are to be displayed based on their col/row values. It would be better if I first display all the components in col 0, then col 1 ..

Comment: Oké so you want to display you components in columns and rows but you would like to display them column by column instead of row by row. I'm not an expert but I think usualy you devide everything in rows and than you use CSS classes to specify the column they get displayed in.

Comment: I am ok to display them row by row. But if you see my array, there are components and their row, column value, but not in a specific order. I am wondering how to write the logic to display the items of row 0 first or column 0 first.

Comment: do you have a maximum of columns hardcoded somewhere ?

Comment: I can get that and lets assume we have that information.